# How to group/aggregate using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a db full of data objects similar to books. This applies to book editions too, so if Book A has been printed 9 times, there are 9 examples of it in my database. What links these 9 examples is they have one id, say `book_id`. In my search results, I want to discard all results with the same `book_id` except one, the one with the most recent `published_date`. Thing is, I'm not sure how to get the aggregation to work properly. Here's what I have now:

```
return Book.aggregate([
    { $match: generateMLabQuery(rawQuery) },
    { $group: { _id: '$book_id' } },
```

The first match is simply doing normal matching things, like searching by author or genre or whatever. I was under the impression that `$group` would then compress all the results by unique `book_id`, but it's not the case, since what I get returned is simply an array of items that look like `{ _id: earg684rthae68g486e }`. How do I get it to return the full Book document, but with all old releases discarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the link between these books is 'book_id', it's clear that you need to group by 'book_id' field, that means for every 'book_id', you'll get an array of books.

```
return Book.aggregate([
    { $match: generateMLabQuery(rawQuery) },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$book_id",
            books: {
                $push: "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The above will give you an array of documents for each book_id in the books field.

But you only need one book for each book_id and that needs to be the one with the latest 'published_date', so if you sort the results on the basis of 'published_date' in descending order, you can just get the first object of the array everytime.

```
return Book.aggregate([
    { $match: generateMLabQuery(rawQuery) },
    {
        $sort: {
            "published_date": -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$book_id",
            books: {
                $first: "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: This almost does the trick. What I get though is an array of objects that have an `_id` field I don't need, and all the useful info behind a redundant `books` object. Is there a way to simply return the result of that `$group` call without the `_id` and the `books` object, i.e. the same structure as if I'd just done the `$match`?

Comment: Turns out I got an answer for the above question is `replaceRoot`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489090/return-original-documents-only-from-mongoose-group-aggregation-operation

Answer (score 0):

Group creates new objects; you can manipulate `$first` / `$last` accumulator operators to digest fields you need, and then `$project` them:

```
return Book.aggregate([
  { $match: generateMLabQuery(rawQuery) },
  { 
    $group: {
      _id: '$book_id',
      published_date: { $last: '$published_date' },
      title: { $first: '$title' },
      author: { $first: '$author' }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: '$id',
      book_id: '$_id',
      published_date: 1,
      title: 1,
      author: 1
    }
  }
])
```