# Return original documents only from mongoose group/aggregation operation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a filter + group operation on a bunch of documents (books). The grouping is to return only latest versions of books that share the same `book_id` (name). The below code works, but it's untidy since it returns redundant information:

```
return Book.aggregate([
    { $match: generateMLabQuery(rawQuery) },
    {
        $sort: {
            "published_date": -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$book_id",
            books: {
                $first: "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

I end up with an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[{ _id: "aedrtgt6854earg864", books: { singleBookObject } }, {...}, {...}]
```

Essentially I only need the `singleBookObject` part, which is the original document (and what I'd be getting if I had done only the `$match` operation). Is there a way to get rid of the redundant `_id` and `books` parts within the aggregation pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)

```
Book.aggregate([
  { "$match": generateMLabQuery(rawQuery) },
  { "$sort": { "published_date": -1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$book_id",
    "books": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$books" } }
])
```